# How can I tell ASP.NET MVC Role Manager to use my implementation of IUserRoleStore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity

The title says it. I've implemented custom IUserRoleStore, now how do I make the framework call it when i use AuthorizeAttribute or User.IsInRole?

Comment: Using the Microsoft-provided Entity Framework UserStore or your own custom UserStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity that carries the claims & roles gets created by the `UserManager`, which gets passed a `UserStore` on creation. In case you have your own implementation of the `UserStore`, you just implement the `IUserRoleStore` interface, i.e.

```
public class UserStore : // ...
                         IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>,
                         // ...
```

In case you use the Entity Framework `UserStore` that comes with the templates, you should be able to override it like that (not tested by me, just a guess):

```
public class MyUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    public override Task AddToRoleAsync(IdentityUser user, string role)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then when you create your `UserManager`, you pass it the derived `UserStore`.

**UPDATE**

This code creates an identity

```
var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("someclaim", "somevalue"));
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
```

which gets stored in the encrypted cookie (or token) and is made available by the OWIN middleware via `IPrincipal`. That's why you can read back user properties without hitting the database, e.g.

```
private string GetClaim(string claimType)
{
    var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    return principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == claimType).Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or via `User.IsInRole()` / `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

It works for me and I'm using the `AuthorizeAttribute` with roles, e.g.

```
[RoutePrefix("account"), Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
// ...
```

When signing a user in, `GetRolesAsync` on the `UserStore` gets called, on subsequent visits the roles are available from the cookie. I'm using this [UserStore](https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity). MySQL is [here.](https://github.com/raquelsa/AspNet.Identity.MySQL) Make sure your `UserStore` implements the `IUserRoleStore` interface, otherwise it won't be able to get the roles.

Comment: I know. But this UserStore is in the scope of AccountController, how could it be relevant to AuthorizeAttribute set on a different contrller. My implementation also has methods from IUserStore interface which are getting called when they should. Its the methods from IUserRoleStore that never get called.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthorizeAttribute/User.IsInRole looks for any RoleClaimTypes in the ClaimsIdentity for your User IPrincipal.  The UserManager's ClaimsIdentityFactory typically generates those claims via the IUserRoleStore when its generating the ClaimsIdentity that turns into your sign in cookie.  But its not directly going to call your custom IUserRoleStore methods as part of checking for role membership.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your web.config does not enable the old role manager when using the new ASP.NET Identity framework with your custom UserManager. Be sure to set it to false.

```
        <system.web>
     <roleManager enabled="false" />
   </system.web>
```

This was set to true in one of our projects and almost drove us crazy with strange sql exceptions whenever we tried to use .IsInRole or [Authorize]